# What is the advantage of key-value storage?

Tags: cassandra, key-value, key-value-store, nosql

I am quite confusing what is the difference between a key-value storage like Cassandra compared to a distributed database with a table containing two columns. One column called key, the other called value, and indexed on the key.

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking about the representation of the data while the term "key-value" is actually describing the underlying storage mechanism. The term "key-value" in Cassandra refers to the fact that data is inherently stored based on the `partition key` of the data. This key value determine on which node and with which other data it is stored. Within each partition (as defined by a single partition key) rows are ordered by the clustering columns. This means looking data up within a partition can be done quite quickly but looking data that spans multiple partitions will be more expensive.

I suggest you look into some CQL data-modeling examples to understand more about how the underlying storage mechanism works.

[CQL Under the Hood](http://www.slideshare.net/rastrick/cql-under-the-hood-39023557)